# jQuery: Custom function doen't respond

Tags: jquery, function

I trie to write a simple validation function. For some response I can't get the function to return the boolean. For now I got no response from clicking submit at all.

```
$.fn.ValidateSelect = function() {
//function ValidateSelect() { (this works)

    var selected = $('select[name="my-item-size"]').val();

    var validate = false;

    if (selected != 'none') {               
        validate = true;    
    } else {
        validate = false;
    }

    if (validate == true) {             
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
};


//submit
$('.add_item_button').click(function() {    

    if (ValidateSelect() == true) {
        $('#item_submit').submit();
    } else {
        alert('Please select your brand first.')
}

});
```

Comment: You are not calling the function. `ValidateSelect` is a variable name and will be `undefined`. If you are extending the jQuery like this, you'd rather call it with `$(selector).ValidateSelect()`. But maybe a simple, normal function is sufficient for you.

Comment: I made it a normal function now, and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a jQuery extension but a javascript function.

```
 function ValidateSelect() {

    var selected = $('select[name="my-item-size"]').val();

    var validate = false;

    if (selected != 'none') {               
        validate = true;    
    } else {
        validate = false;
    }

    if (validate == true) {             
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
};


//submit
$('.add_item_button').click(function() {    

    if (ValidateSelect() == true) {
        $('#item_submit').submit();
    } else {
        alert('Please select your brand first.')
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

i believe it should be $.ValidateSelect() == true. Calling ValidateSelect by itself would mean its a variable, not a function specifically here.

Also i think it might make more sense to put it in a regular function outside of jQuery (at least by it seems)

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually call the function:-

```
$('.add_item_button').click(function() {    

    if (ValidateSelect() == true) {
        $('#item_submit').submit();
    } else {
        alert('Please select your brand first.')
}
```